# Postgress, how to guarantee sequenciality in multithread solution

Tags: postgresql, multithreading, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a clustered application that has to insert huge number of transactions into the database. the primary key for this table is a bigserial so the sequence is automatically handled by Postgress ( I'm using pg 14 ).
the issue I'm facing is that with Postgress session set as multi thread the transactions insert into the DB are not sequencial.
I'm noticing this looking at the insert timestamp. So based on my search my understanding is that PG is queuing the insert received by the application and at that time it does pick the nextval from the sequence keeping it in cache till the time of the real insert happen, while instead the current_timestamp is valorized only at the time of the effective writing into the table. So sometimes there are some misalignment since a older sequence have a newer timestamp then a newer sequence.

| id | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-04-19 18:59:43.879212 |
| 2 | 2023-04-19 18:59:43.878113 |
| 3 | 2023-04-19 18:59:44.128732 |
| 4 | 2023-04-19 18:59:44.579221 |
| 5 | 2023-04-19 18:59:45.600507 |

as per the example above the id 2 have been insert few millis before the id 1.
Is there any way in PG to force the system to get the sequence val at the time of insert and not when it receives the query?
Or any other solution that can safely guarantee the sequenciality?

I've tried also setting the specific postgress session as single thread, but it didn't help. Even do the session is single thread the queries are enqueued by PG and executed as soon as the specific process is getting eligible which is not properly FIFO.

Comment: That’s how a sequence works, it gives you a number and that’s it. Don’t give this number any other meaning, it’s not a sort order, or something else, it’s just a number

Comment: Right.  Elements in an SQL database do not have any inherent order.  If you need to read the records in time order, then you must do `ORDER BY timestamp`.

Comment: In general, surrogate keys should only serve as unique row identifiers: they shouldn't carry any other semantic value. Any method that guarantees monotonically increasing IDs with time requires serialized processes. Even if run in parallel threads, the need to coordinate ID generation between threads reduces the aggregate operation to a serial process.

Comment: thank you @JohnH the serialization is one option but as side effect have a direct impact on the performances... I was wondering if there is any construct or solution at DB level in alternative to the sequences that is used by the DB at the level of the insert rather then when the query is received by the DB system.

Comment: @Released, you might try using `clock_timestamp`; however, there is no guarantee that parallel processes won't attempt inserts at the same time. As I said, a surrogate key should serve only to identify a specific row. When using parallel processes, it is a waste of effort to try to force them to be strictly increasing with time.